# How/where is opname populated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at the dis module source code in Python 3.7, one thing puzzles me, I do not see `opname` is defined yet it is directly used. E.g. here is how it is accessed:

```
348         yield Instruction(opname[op], op,
349                           arg, argval, argrepr,
350                           offset, starts_line, is_jump_target)
```

But where is opname populated?

Here is a list of all the occurrances of "opname":

```
Lib>grep -n "\<opname\>" dis.py
185:     "opname opcode arg argval argrepr offset starts_line is_jump_target")
187:_Instruction.opname.__doc__ = "Human readable name for operation"
203:         opname - human readable name for operation
241:        fields.append(self.opname.ljust(_OPNAME_WIDTH))
348:        yield Instruction(opname[op], op,
```

I greped "opname" in C source code also, does not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the earlier line `from opcode import *`. The `opname` list is populated in [`opcode.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/opcode.py), the contents of which are fairly straightforward.